# Azure Redis session state timeout issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

Is there any way to increase default timeout if i am using azure redis(2.4 version) and passing the connecting string in a .net framework application.

Also i am using redis for sessionstate management

‘’’ Timeout issue. ‘’’

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented.You can follow this nuget package to get information about the same

```
<sessionState timeout="20" mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
      <providers>
         <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
            host = "dummy.redis.cache.windows.net" 
            port = "6380" 
            accessKey = "dummysecretkey" 
            ssl = "true" 
            throwOnError = "true" 
            retryTimeoutInMilliseconds = "5000" 
            databaseId = "0" 
            applicationName = "" 
            connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds = "5000" 
            operationTimeoutInMilliseconds = "1000" 
            connectionString = ""
            />  
      </providers>
</sessionState>
```

https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/redis-cache/cache-asp.net-session-state-provider.md